# Do I need a visa for the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, iraqi-citizens

I am an Iraqi holder passport, and I have EU residency in Poland. Also I have UAE residency. If I visit the UK as tourist for one month, do I need to apply for a visa?

Answer (score 4):

> You’ll need a visa to come to the UK

Source: [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iraq/tourism/no)